# Notation for the union of all the sets in a family.

Tags: notation

Does anyone know how to write the following:
If $\mathcal{F}$ is a family of sets, I want the union of all $X$ in this $\mathcal{F}$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just check this thread? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276104/online-mathjax-editor

Comment: This is not a math question. Flagged.

Comment: In some sense this is not a question about $\TeX$ or formatting, it's a question about the correct symbol and syntax to indicate the union of a family of sets. I don't see it so off-topic. Maybe it could be reworded...

Comment: If the question is reworded so that it asks for the current notation for union of family of sets, then I say reopen it. But if it specifically is about one can typeset something in LaTeX, then I say migrate it. Maybe the OP could scan a picture of what he is trying to do in LaTeX, then the Tex-people would know what the best way to do that is.

Comment: This looks like more of a math notation question than a $\TeX$ question.  The Help Center is unclear about whether such a question belongs here.

Comment: On second thought, the fact that a (notation) flag even exists suggests that the question does belong here.  This a notation question.

Comment: IF the OP could agree to the changing of his question, then I am also fine with how it stands now. However, the original question asked specifically about how to do something in LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

Use $\bigcup_{X  \in \mathcal F} X$ or simply $\bigcup \mathcal F$.

Comment: In code this would be `$\bigcup_{x\in\mathcal{F}}X$` or `$\bigcup\mathcal{F}$`.

Answer (score 1):

This probably should be migrated to tex.SE.

But:

$$
\bigcup_{X\in \mathcal{F}} X
$$
would work.

Comment: But would the typographers there know about the math background of th equestion?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Maybe you are right. I would guess that they would.

Answer (score 0):

Use $\bigcup_i X_i$, if $\mathcal F=\{X_1,X_2,\dots\}$.

Comment: How do you know that $\mathcal{F}$ is countable?

Comment: I did not know it: I thought that the OP needed the union symbol, after all...instead of counting the "i"'s one can write $X\in\mathcal F$ under the union.